# Is there a stochaistic matrix with an eigen value in the interval (0,1). any example will do.

Tags: probability, matrices

Unless I did something very wrong, I don't think there should be an eigen value for a stochaistic matrix in that interval.

Note, the stochaistic matrix doesn't even need to be regular, and the eigenvectors, don't have to be probability vectors either.

Comment: As you wrote in the title, *any example* will do. Well, not any, but almost any stochastic matrix will have such eigenvalue. Just try something simple.

Comment: @zhoraster "Almost any" is perhaps a bit exaggerated. People tend to test hypotheses about linear algebra using small matrices. The probability that a 2x2 stochastic matrix has an eigenvalue inside (0,1) is 3/4. It is a high value, but nowhere near certainty.

Comment: @user1551, of course, this is a bit exaggerated. But not too much - the probability that a randomly chosen stochastic $n\times n$ matrix has an eigenvalue inside $(0,1)$ will be converging to $1$ as $n\to\infty$; moreover, AFAIK there will be around $c\log n$ such eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your statement is true for $1\times 1$ matrices, so let's look at the next-simplest case, $2\times 2$ matrices with one trivial row:

$$M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\1-a & a\end{array}\right].$$

What are the eigenvalues of $M$?